# Ubuntu Server Installation is Getting Stuck

Tags: server, raid, ibm

I have been trying to install Ubuntu server on my IBM x3550 server to replace windows server; and the installation was doing just fine until it reached "Running live-installer-console-setup" at which point everything stops, and the progression bar never moves past 76% no matter how much time I give it. The version I am trying to install is 14.04 and the hardware is as follows: - 2x SAS IBM HDD 70.6GB in RAID - IBM serverRaid-8k raid card - 2x Intel Xeon E5245 - 4x 4GB ddr2 memory

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Figure this out?  I am stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got my install to work by removing the RAID card from my server.  I also changed the boot drive to be a plain SATA drive, I was trying motherboard raid 1 for a redundant boot drive, once that was done the install completed.  I was then able to plug the RAID card back in and access the files on the array.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same symptoms. I was installing some test VMs within Hyper-V and got stuck at the same screen. I clicked on the windows and hit enter a couple of times, and then selected Shutdown in the Hyper-V connection toolbar which immediately got things rolling again... despite that there is now a little progress indicator at the bottom of the Hyper-V window, I am now on configuration of the package manager.